# How to compare two time string check if string2 is grater then first string in swift

Tags: ios, swift, dateformatter

I am new in swift I search this questing and also got answer but not worked for me. Sorry for asking this again. My question is how to compare two time string. I am using this code.

```
let date = Date()
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        let result = formatter.string(from: date)
        print(result)
        
        var totalTimeLoggedIn = TimeInterval() // 1 hour
        
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        
        let loginTimeDate = dateFormatter.date(from: lblWorkStarted.text ?? "")!
        let logoutTimeDate = dateFormatter.date(from: result)!
        
        
        let timeLoggedIn = logoutTimeDate.timeIntervalSince(loginTimeDate)
        totalTimeLoggedIn += timeLoggedIn
        print("totalTimeLoggedIn: \(totalTimeLoggedIn.stringValue())")
        let TotalTimeLoginString = totalTimeLoggedIn.stringValue()
        let anotherdate = "02:00:00"
        
        if anotherdate < TotalTimeLoginString{
            print("True")
            
        }else{
            
        }
```

lblWorkStarted.text is the current date and time.
I am facing problem is that if TotalTimeLoginString is "10:15" some value like this then condition is not working properly and if  TotalTimeLoginString is "03:12:11" some value like this then it is working properly.
My problem is if I did not get hour then condition is not working. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have some mistakes here:

- You should create DateFormatter() again. It's heavy operation as https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW10
- You have to differentiate date and duration. Today is 8/4/2020, you can't compare it with duration as 1 hour, 2 hours.
- if your `anotherdate` is two hours, why you don't compare it as: `2 * 60 * 60 <  totalTimeLoggedIn` ?

  ```
   let date = Date()

   let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
   dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

   let loginTimeDate = dateFormatter.date(from: lblWorkStarted.text ?? "")!
   let timeLoggedIn = Date().timeIntervalSince(loginTimeDate)
   let anotherDate = 2 * 60 * 60

   if anotherDate < timeLoggedIn {
       print("True")

   }else{

   }
  ```